# python boto3 attach/replace IAM role to ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I could not find a way to attach/replace an IAM role to the EC2 instance via boto3.
The documentation at [cloudhackers](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection) provides a method to run image with IAM role, but not to attach.

Is it possible with boto? Otherwise, I need to do it manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the docs [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.associate_iam_instance_profile)

**associate_iam_instance_profile(**kwargs)**
Associates an IAM instance profile with a running or stopped instance. You cannot associate more than one IAM instance profile with an instance.

Request Syntax

```
response = client.associate_iam_instance_profile(
    IamInstanceProfile={
        'Arn': 'string',
        'Name': 'string'
    },
    InstanceId='string'
)
```

Response Syntax

```
{
    'IamInstanceProfileAssociation': {
        'AssociationId': 'string',
        'InstanceId': 'string',
        'IamInstanceProfile': {
            'Arn': 'string',
            'Id': 'string'
        },
        'State': 'associating'|'associated'|'disassociating'|'disassociated',
        'Timestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    }
}
```

By the way, the link you gave has a banner on top saying

> Note You are viewing the documentation for an older version of boto
>   (boto2). Boto3, the next version of Boto, is now stable and
>   recommended for general use.